# Rails - conditionally log for a specific hostname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, conditional-statements, production-environment

I'm looking for a way to configure a Rails server log only if the client has contacted a specific hostname. e.g. I could make it so that http://public.example.com doesn't get logged, but http://debug.example.com (same underlying Rails app server) does get logged (or ideally gets logged in more detail than the regular host). It would help with production debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gem [Lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) to customize your log. This gem will give you much more custom to your log. For example, in your case, I will do this

After install the gem. Create a file at `config/initializers/lograge.rb`

```
# config/initializers/lograge.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.lograge.enabled = true

  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    # custom log on specific domain
    if event.payload[:host] == "debug.example.com"
      {:host => event.payload[:host]}
    else
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

And in your `Application Controller`

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # This will add request's host to lograge so you can use it to filter log later
  def append_info_to_payload(payload)
    super
    payload[:host] = request.host
  end
end
```

Now you can customize your log base on domain, on how to customize it please read at: https://github.com/roidrage/lograge

Comment: Very cool. I already use Lograge in some environments ... didn't realise it makes customising easier.